# Storm Door modification

Tags: doors

I'm trying to install a storm door on the back of my house.  The house is older and the door jam seems to have been modified to an odd width on the exterior of the house.  A 36" door will be too large and a 32" door will be too small.  The actual width is around 35-5/8".  Any idea's on how to add additional framing which will accommodate a 32" door? Thank you.

Comment: Buy a 36" door and trim 3/8" off?  Depending on the door that will either be fine ... or cause it to fall to pieces.

Comment: Can you post a few photos. Most likely you can remove the portion of the jamb that's been modified and find the appropriate size wood to replace it (search brick molding). Did you search for a 34' door? That may work but will still require shimming and look a little better.

Comment: Thank you both for the help.  The type of door that I am buying has a pet door at the bottom and I have not seen that type offered as a 44" but I will look.  I will take some pictures this evening and post tomorrow.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the 36" door you want won't fit in a 35 5/8" space?  The door might be made for jambs with a small margin of error.

Answer (score 2):

Your first option is to see if there is any addition to the door jamb that can be removed to give you a standard width.  Sometimes there is additional molding added that may appear to be one piece, but it can be removed.  If it's not trim, you may even be able to modify the jamb with a router to give you a little extra size on either edge (more advanced, but cost effective if you have the tools).

If the jamb is an odd size, then you can get odd sized storm doors.  They might not have them in stock, but sizes like 34" can be ordered.  Get the closest size available and add trim to make it fit.

As a random example, [this Andersen door](https://custom.homedepot.com/custom-doors/p/Andersen-3000-Series-Full-View-Interchangeable-Aluminum-Storm-Door/306553494/) can be ordered at 33", 34" or 36" (not recommending this door, just a quick example of odd sizes).  If you call around, you might even be able to find a 35" door.  There are shops that specialize in doors and windows and they might be your best bet.

Comment: Order a 34" ... and then cut a hole in it for a pet door.